# How to install lighttpd with php?

Tags: debian, web-server

I've installed `lighttpd`, and it is working fine. I've tried to install php5 as described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/905/how-do-i-install-lighttpd-lighty-on-debian-squeeze), but when I try the last step

```
sudo service lighttpd force-reload
```

I get:

```
[FAIL] Reloading web server configuration: lighttpd failed!
```

and php is not working.

My `lighttpd` configuration can be found at http://pastebin.com/eagG4SwF:

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_fastcgi",
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
#       "mod_rewrite",
)

        server.document-root        = "/mnt/www"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80
        server.follow-symlink       = "enable"
        server.dir-listing          = "enable"
        dir-listing.encoding = "utf-8"

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

Comment: There is a problem with the configuration file; please post it.

Comment: here is my lighttpd configuration  http://pastebin.com/eagG4SwF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got mine working by following instruction from [Running a lightweight webserver on the Raspberry Pi (lighttpd)](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/light-webserver).

Summary of the steps required following the link above.

1. Install lighttpd -> `sudo apt-get install lighttpd`
2. Install mysql database (optional) -> `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`
   mysql root password will be prompt upon completion of installation
3. Install PHP -> `sudo apt-get install php5-common php5-cgi php5 php5-mysql`

   > **NOTE** it's important to install in the order listed above. If you try to
   >   install php5 without first installing the php5-cgi package then it will
   >   install Apache as well, which we don't want for this light-weight lighttpd
   >   server.
4. Install php mysql libraries -> `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`
5. Enable lighttpd to handle php -> `sudo lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php` followed
   by reloading lighttpd `sudo service lighttpd force-reload`
6. Set permission for /var/www -> `sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www`, then
   allow group to write to the dir `sudo chmod 775 /var/www`, followed by adding
   `pi` to the `www-data` group `sudo usermod -a -G www-data pi`
7. Logout/Login to pickup group permission so `pi` can also write to the
   `/var/www dir`

Comment: What if apache got installed, when I installed php using just: apt-get install php5 ? How can I return to the previous state?

Comment: @Euphorbium you can remove it by `sudo apt-get autoremove apache` or whichever version of apache you've installed. The reason to use `autoremove` is to remove dependency as well. http://superuser.com/questions/398670/when-would-you-use-apt-get-remove-over-apt-get-autoremove

Comment: As the top result on Google I thought it worth pointing out that the command to install php is now `sudo apt-get install php-common php-cgi php php-mysql`

Answer (score 1):

I have lighttpd/php working on my Pi:

I also have moved my `www` folder to a mounted drive.

In my case I've sim-linked `/var/www` to the folder on  `/mnt/usb/www` (as I have it), rather than changing the config in lighttpd.conf itself.

The other thing that stands out doing a comparison is that I have the section below at the end of the file:

```
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" => ((
                     "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php5-cgi",
                     "socket" => "/tmp/php.socket"
                 )))
```

I'll try to find the instructions I followed to set it all up and edit here.

Edit: I may have based my setup on [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/lighttpd_mysql_php_debian_etch) but I can't be sure.

Comment: I've tried it that way, and it does not work.